# ReferenceError: Worker is not defined while testing AppRouter Component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing a React/Typescript component using Jest and React Testing-Library. I am doing a simple render test and getting a `Reference Error: Worker is not defined`.

Why and how would I use a worker in this testing context?

Here is my simple test:

```
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import React from 'react'
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import AppRouter from '../router'

test('AppRouter renders all routes and I can navigate to those pages', () => {
    render(<AppRouter />)
    screen.debug()
})
```

And here is the AppRouter component:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState } from 'react'

import useLocalStorage from './hooks/useLocalStorage'
import * as Constants from './constants'

import Header from './layout/header/header'
import MainPage from './pages/mainPage/mainPage'
import PostPage from './pages/postPage/postPage'
import UserPage from './pages/userPage/userPage'
import LoginPage from './pages/loginPage/loginPage'
import SignupPage from './pages/signupPage/signupPage'
import NewPage from './pages/newPage/newPage'
import FeedbackPage from './pages/feedbackPage/feedbackPage'
import AdminPage from './pages/adminPage/adminPage'
import SettingPage from './pages/settingPage/settingPage'

import { WebContext } from './context/WebContext'
import Favicon from 'react-favicon'

const AppRouter = () => {
    const [adminCode, setAdminCode] = useLocalStorage('admin', '')
    const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false)
    const [page, setPage] = useState(Constants.Page.Home)

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Favicon url={require('../public/favicon.ico')} />
                <WebContext.Provider
                    value={{
                        isMenuOpen,
                        setIsMenuOpen,
                        page,
                        setPage,
                        adminCode,
                        setAdminCode,
                    }}
                >
                    <Header />

                    <Switch>
                        <Route component={MainPage} path="/" exact={true} />
                        <Route component={PostPage} path="/post/:id" />
                        <Route component={UserPage} path="/user" />
                        <Route component={LoginPage} path="/login" />
                        <Route component={SignupPage} path="/signup" />
                        <Route component={NewPage} path="/new" />
                        <Route component={FeedbackPage} path="/feedback" />
                        <Route component={AdminPage} path="/admin" />
                        <Route component={SettingPage} path="/setting" />
                        <Route component={() => <Redirect to="/" />} />
                    </Switch>
                </WebContext.Provider>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default AppRouter
```

Most of what I researched on this were old Jest stackoverflows. I am aware there is a jest-worker package but not sure why I would need this or how I would use it when running this simple test.
[***Here***](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/main/packages/jest-worker) is a link to jest-worker.

**Code Trace:**
[image]

**Header component**

```
import { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { NavLink, useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'

import { WebContext } from '../../context/WebContext'
import UnirepContext from '../../context/Unirep'
import UserContext from '../../context/User'

const Header = () => {
    const history = useHistory()
    const location = useLocation()
    const { isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen } = useContext(WebContext)
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState<string>('')
    const unirepConfig = useContext(UnirepContext)
    const userContext = useContext(UserContext)

    const gotoNewPage = () => {
        if (
            userContext.userState &&
            userContext.netReputation >= unirepConfig.postReputation
        ) {
            history.push(`/new`, { isConfirmed: true })
        }
    }

    const gotoUserPage = () => {
        history.push(`/user`, { isConfirmed: true })
    }

    const openMenu = () => {
        if (!isMenuOpen) {
            console.log('open menu!')
            setIsMenuOpen(true)
        }
    }

    const handleSearchInput = (event: any) => {
        console.log('search input : ' + event.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <header>
            <div className="navLinks">
                <NavLink to="/" className="link" activeClassName="active" exact>
                    <img
                        src={require('../../../public/images/unirep-title.svg')}
                    />
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            {/* <div className="search-bar">
                <div className="search-icon"><FaSearch /></div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="searchInput" placeholder="Search by keyword, user names or epoch key" onChange={handleSearchInput} />
                </form>
            </div> */}
            {userContext.userState ? (
                <div className="navButtons">
                    <div id="rep" onClick={gotoUserPage}>
                        <img
                            src={require('../../../public/images/lighting.svg')}
                        />
                        {userContext.netReputation}
                    </div>
                    <div
                        id="new"
                        className={
                            location.pathname === '/new'
                                ? 'navBtn chosen'
                                : 'navBtn'
                        }
                    >
                        <img
                            src={require('../../../public/images/newpost.svg')}
                            onClick={gotoNewPage}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div
                        id="user"
                        className={
                            location.pathname === '/user'
                                ? 'navBtn chosen'
                                : 'navBtn'
                        }
                    >
                        <img
                            src={require('../../../public/images/user.svg')}
                            onClick={gotoUserPage}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="navBtn">
                        <img
                            src={require('../../../public/images/menu.svg')}
                            onClick={openMenu}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div className="navButtons">
                    <div
                        id="login"
                        className="whiteButton"
                        onClick={() => history.push('/login')}
                    >
                        Sign in
                    </div>
                    <div
                        id="join"
                        className="blackButton"
                        onClick={() => history.push('/signup')}
                    >
                        Join
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu" className="navBtn">
                        <img
                            src={require('../../../public/images/menu.svg')}
                            onClick={openMenu}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </header>
    )
}

export default observer(Header)
```

**EDIT**

The problem may stem from using MobX for state management and not wrapping the component in a Provider but still unsure of how to do this.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the full error message and accompanying code stacktrace? What "Worker" isn't defined? The stacktrace in the console will generally include the code/file and line number, and is a link that you can follow and view the source. For debugging you could also try reducing the complexity of the `AppRouter` component until the test passes, and then incrementally add a component back one-at-a-time, until the test breaks. This can help you zero in on the offending code.

Comment: @DrewReese For sure, just added the code trace.

Comment: So it *looks* like the error is originating somewhere in the `Header` component where it's rendering/accessing a `User.ts` context "thing". If you comment out the `Header` component does the test work? What is the `Header` component doing? Can you share *that* code?

Comment: @DrewReese I commented out component to see if there was an issue with one of them and would get the test passing, and still got failures. But, when I commented out the ```<Header />``` component AND everything within ```<Switch />``` (including the switch) the test passes and I do not get any error.

Comment: @DrewReese just added the header component. And the test still fails if I _only_ comment out the ```Header``` component.

Comment: It looked like there was still some issue coming from the `userContext`. I see now you are using mobx... is it the case that you need to provide context providers for the mobx state and these other contexts (*`WebContext`, `UnirepContext`, `UserContext`, the `observer`, etc...*) your UI code is consuming? What is `User.ts` doing?

Comment: User.ts is exporting a class with createContext from react. And I am not sure why I would need this for Jest/Testing-Library tests. In other words, the unit-tests should not care about context. @DrewReese

Comment: @DrewReese To be more clear, ```User.ts``` is a store. Currently figuring out how to create a ```test-utils.tsx``` file to create a wrapper around the components during testing.